# Как правильно передать объект в промисе?

Tags: javascript

Доброй ночи, ребята.

Есть небольшой вопрос.

Есть функция Которая чистит массив объектов.

Результат этой функции я передаю далее по цепочке .then 
и после передачи перестаёт работать перебор данного объекта.

В чем причина подскажите кто знает.

```js
const remDupl = function (arr, fild) {
    var rez = {news:[]};
    var lookupObject  = {};

    for(var i in arr) {
        lookupObject[arr[i][fild]] = arr[i];
    }

    for( i in lookupObject) {
        rez.news.push(lookupObject[i]);
    }
    return rez;
};
```

как можно убедиться далее все тут работает хорошо.

```js
const remDupl = function (arr, fild) {
    var rez = {news:[]};
    var lookupObject  = {};

    for(var i in arr) {
        lookupObject[arr[i][fild]] = arr[i];
    }

    for( i in lookupObject) {
        rez.news.push(lookupObject[i]);
    }
    return rez;
};


let arr={
    news : [
        {'title': 'one'},
        {'title': 'two'},
        {'title': 'three'},
        {'title': 'four', 'name': 'dima'},
        {'title': 'four', 'name': 'alex'},
        {'title': 'one', 'name': 'alex'},
    ]
};



let rec = remDupl(arr.news, 'title');

console.log(rec);
```

Однако Дело обстоит Хуже когда перебается результат этой функции далее через промисы.

добавляется почему то? инекс 0 и все бы ничего но даже про этому адресу перебором через forEach резуль --- тат Пустота

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит тест этой функции

```
let rec = remDupl(arr.news, 'title');
console.log(rec);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как выглядит объект после передачи промисом

```
console.log(cleanArr);
```

Как видно добавился индекс 0 откуда ? И почему не работает на нём перебор?

вывод предыдущего промиса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  .then(pulledNews => {
    return remDupl(pulledNews, 'title');
})
.then(cleanArr => {
    // console.log(cleanArr);
    cleanArr.news[0].forEach(item=>{console.log(item)});
})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажи функцию которая возвращает промис.

Comment: @LevShportak  добавил в конце см.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы хотели чего-то такого? -

```js
const remDupl = function (arr, fild) {
    var rez = {news:[]};
    var lookupObject  = {};

    for(var i in arr) {
        lookupObject[arr[i][fild]] = arr[i];
    }

    for( i in lookupObject) {
        rez.news.push(lookupObject[i]);
    }
    return rez;
};

new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  let arr = {
    news: [
      { 'title': 'one' },
      { 'title': 'two' },
      { 'title': 'three' },
      { 'title': 'four', 'name': 'dima' },
      { 'title': 'four', 'name': 'alex' },
      { 'title': 'one', 'name': 'alex' }
    ]
  };
  resolve(arr);
})
.then(pulledNews => remDupl(pulledNews.news, 'title'))
.then(cleanArr   => cleanArr.news.forEach(item => console.log(item)));
```

Comment: все вроде норм а что вас смущает??

Comment: добавил скрин вывода как вы просили.